# Замена значения ключа в файле json

Tags: java, json, gson

Есть файл с настройками стороннего приложения json. В файле есть координаты GPS, которые надо изменить на мои.
Пример содержимого файла:

```
{
  "map": {
    "lng": 37.01236582545265,
    "lat": 54.98325589056621,
    "speed": 1.9,
    "radius": 1.0,
  },
}
```

второй день бьюсь над этим, не могу поменять координаты для `lng` и `lat`.
Собственно, даже прочитать значения `lng` и `lat` не получается:

```
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonElement jsonElement = parser.parse("C:\\Users\\...\\test.json");
JsonObject rootObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
JsonObject childObject = rootObject.getAsJsonObject("map");
String place = childObject.get("lat").getAsString();

System.out.println(place);
```

Помогите с кодом для чтения, а самое главное для замены значений `lat` и `lng`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я использую **minimal-json** поэтому код вот такой:

p.s.: ваш json я немного подправил - убрал запятые в конце
Вычитывает json из файла, в файле тоже что и в строке String, только без экранирований кавычек конечно. Сохраняет в файл новый json.

```
try {
    //Read from file
    String jsonn = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("/home/ufo/1.txt")));
    //Read from String
    //String jsonn = "{ \"map\": {\"lng\": 37.01236582545265, \"lat\": 54.98325589056621, \"speed\": 1.9, \"radius\": 1.0 }  }";
    JsonValue value = Json.parse(jsonn);  
    value.asObject().get("map").asObject().set("lng", 16.2222222);
    value.asObject().get("map").asObject().set("lat", 17.3333333);
    //Debug
    System.out.println(value.toString());
    //Write to file
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("/home/ufo/1.txt", "UTF-8");
    writer.println(value.toString());
    writer.close();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Оба кода работают правильно если String jsonn = "{ \"map\": {\"lng\": 37.01236582545265, \"lat\": 54.98325589056621, \"speed\": 1.9, \"radius\": 1.0 }  }";   Если указываю путь к файлу, то не читаются значения из файла. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Подправил код. Для чтения из файла добавил строчку